# Findstr not returning expected result

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Hi all I have the following line of code to list all the files that matches the word `Hello`

```
findstr /s "Hello" .\*.* > C:\MyDir\result.txt
```

I am having multiples files inside my folder as `file1.xml` and `file2.xml` but when I execute this script it is giving me only `file1.xml` but not the `file2.xml` can some one help me. Content inside my both files is `<Hello></Hello>` and `<Hello>`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `FINDSTR` is a plain old executable; the (more powerful) PowerShell equivalent is `Select-String`. Try `dir -recurse | select-string hello`.

Comment: Hi I would like to work out using windows commands for testing purpose I am using PowerShell

Comment: No luck still seeing one file

Comment: `findstr /s /n /i /m "Function" * > C:\MyDir\result.txt`

Comment: you can join `findstr` switches as in `findstr /sinm "blahblah" ...`

Comment: The command is looking for the string "Hello" inside the files; not the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your casing is correct and you want case-sensitive matching (use `/i` to make matches case-insensitive) I would suspect that your second file is Unicode-encoded. You can verify that by opening the file in Notepad and clicking *File → SaveAs...*. The *Encoding* dropdown at the bottom of the SaveAs dialog shows the current encoding of the file.

[`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459.aspx) can't handle Unicode files, but [`find`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655.aspx) can (Raymond Chen [explained why there are two commands](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963)). However, `find` can't recurse into subfolders, so you'd need either a [`for`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx) loop

```
for /r %f in (*.*) do find "Hello" "%~ff"
```

or [`forfiles`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx):

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c find \"Hello\" @path"
```

---

With that said, since you seem to be dealing with XML files there you may want to use PowerShell instead of CMD commands, not only because it handles ANSI and Unicode transparently, but also because it comes with a builtin XML parser.

Depending on what you want to accomplish in the end you could do things like

```
# get full paths for files containing <Hello> nodes
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  Where-Object { ([xml](Get-Content $_)).SelectNodes('//Hello') } |
  Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

or

```
# get all <Hello> nodes
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  ([xml](Get-Content $_)).SelectNodes('//Hello')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might want to check your syntax. You are calling a Write redirect `>` when I think you mean to use the append redirect `>>`. So, your batch file is doing its job... It's just continually overwriting the previous result.

Try this:

```
findstr /s "Hello" .\*.* >> C:\MyDir\result.txt
```

For more information about redirects, see this page on https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: No luck still getting one file name in result

Comment: Hi Nithya, I just created 2 xml files, each containing the following:
`<Hello>Hello</Hello>` and the command successfully found the search term in both files however the result.txt had them shown on the same line. Is it possible that this is also true for you?

Comment: Hello I attached the images, I am having two file but you can see in the result it is showing one file